# Sorting numbers into categories in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-2.14, sorting

I need to sort a column of population figures into categories in a new column so that I can split them out and create layers for each one. Something like 0-99, 100-249, 250-500 etc.

Struggling to figure out a way to do this? See screen grab to show what I mean.

[image: Screen grab]

Comment: You might want to consider updating your QGIS to the latest LTR (2.18) for a more stable working environment.

Comment: I wish it was possible but I am running off a work laptop and our IT won't update our systems any newer than 2.14...

Comment: Did they give any reason for that?

Comment: No, but they don't ever seem to give reasons for anything...!

Comment: Then maybe go talk to your boss, at least in October, when the first 3.x LTR will be released. It'll offer more possibilities and allow for more efficient workflow (or something along that line).

Answer (score 1):

With QGis 2.18 the following will work, with 2.14 it should (I hope so, at least).

Go to the attribute table, `select by expression` and enter the following:

```
"pop" >= 0 AND "pop" <= 99
```

Then save the selected features only to a new file. Repeat for each intended group.

OR: Go to `properties -> style` and choose `graduated`, a bit fiddling, and your groups will be displayed accordingly. Though you'd still have to filter before working on them.